# Fatal error: Call to undefined method ChannelImagesUpdate_50400::update()

Tags: devdemon, channel-images

Fatal error: Call to undefined method ChannelImagesUpdate_50400::update() in /var/www/vhosts/site/sysdata/user/addons/channel_images/upd.channel_images.php on line 215

I recently upgraded a site that was previously running EE 2.11 with the following add-ons: Structure 3.3.14.5, Channel Images 5.2.2 and Expresso 3.3.2. The upgrade went well and the site is now on EE 3.5.2, Structure 4.0.3, and Expresso 4.2.3. I cannot update the Channel Images add-on through the Add-on Manager. It gives the above failure every time I try to run the update. New files have been downloaded from DevDemon and re-uploaded to the correct locations with the same results each time.

A support email to DevDemon has gone unanswered for over a week. Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to line number 215 in UPD file and change the code `$UPD->update();` to `$UPD->do_update();` and run update the module again. :)